# Discord API messaging when another function returns a value

Tags: python, selenium, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am using python discord API https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html and I would like to have a forever loop(like a while loop) That checks with function whether on the site is a new content(I have already wrote a **scraper**). In other words: if **scraper** sees a new post it will return a value(link). I want to connect it with discord and when there is an output of that function, it will be sent to the text channel. I have completely no clue how to do that. The **scraper** function is asynchronous. All that comes to my mind is to make a second thread and log in and then message manually through selenium

Comment: ‘Scrapper’ means someone who throws things away. You mena __scraper__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [webhooks](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook).

Create a [webhook](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks) then whenever your scraper gets new data, submit a POST request to the webhook url you created with the content parameter set to your data.

Example:

```
import requests

WEBHOOK_URL = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/123456789/qWerRYtyuqwfq" # Example webhook url

def sendToDiscord(webhookUrl, data):
    return requests.post(webhookUrl, json={'content': data})
    
data = myScraper.get_data() # Whenever there is data from your scraper
sendToDiscord(WEBHOOK_URL, data) # Send it to Discord
```

**Note:** You can format your message, add images etc... by using the [appropriate](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook-jsonform-params) params

Comment: Really thank you! @FluidLight is it cool to add you somehow on discord / whenever? I would really love to talk with you and ask some questions if I would need to.